# How do I use the Turret Override Program?

Tags: fallout-4

There is a holodisk called the [Turret Override Program](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Turret_override_program), which you obtain by finding a specific [Total Hack magazine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Total_Hack).

Anytime you use a terminal that has turrets connected to it, you can "load" the override program to get additional options.

There is a short readme file that states that "scrambling" the targeting parameters will cause the turrets to shoot everyone, including the player. I cannot for the life of me get this to work the way I expect. There's also a menu option for remote targeting, that makes it seem like you should be able to tell the turrets to shoot at specific targets, but this has never worked for me either.

**How do I use the override program, especially to make the turrets shoot enemies?**

Comment: These programs just appear to be buggy. I have problems with the spotlight one (only one I've found so far).. Sometimes the override program just doesn't work at all. The spotlight continues to target me even after the override. I think it's just going to need to be patched.

Comment: I just noticed [this other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243998/108003), that this might be a duplicate of. It's worded a bit differently. The answer is not at all helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four options when using the override program:

**Sabotage** will cause turrets to explode the next time they fire.

**Scramble** will cause turrets to shoot everyone.

**Override** will cause the turrets to become friendly to the player and hostile to enemy NPCs.

**Remote control** doesn't seem to do anything. Every time it's used it seems to fail.

Note that some of the options aren't always available. Sabotage and override have both been observed to disappear when all turrets connected to the terminal have been destroyed, for example, but not every time.

Also note that if you hit the tab key on PC too quickly, the command might not process. Waiting 2-4 seconds is generally a safe bet. (kudos to aslum in the comments) There are also mods available on Nexus that speed up the terminal output and allow the turret commands to process faster.

Comment: See, that's what I thought those options were supposed to do, but they don't. The only results I've had are the turrets shooting no one or the turrets shooting just me. Or exploding. The exploding one works.

Comment: @DCShannon what platform are you on? I have 100% success on PC, and my brother has the same on XBOne

Comment: I'm on Xbox One. I've tried this with at least half a dozen different turret terminals that still had working turrets, with multiple different characters.

Comment: Most of the time (always?), the Scramble option doesn't show up until after I hit the Override command. Have you found the need to do things in a specific order?

Comment: It might be worth noting, sometimes when using a terminal if you press "back" (TAB on PC) too quickly whatever command you entered will not process... It generally takes about 2-4 seconds for a command to be "enabled" and if you hit back before then it will be canceled instead!

Comment: @aslum That might be it actually. I tend to hammer the A button to skip through the text typing out and immediately back out once it's done typing.

Comment: This seems to be working now. I think @aslum's comment was the key. Add that to the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Additionally, there is at least one mod out there for PC that increases "terminal speed" which might also alleviate this issue...

Comment: @DCShannon it took 2 months but I added it