# Fallout 4 Turrets?

Tags: fallout-4

How do turrets know who to target?
For example if you hack a computer turn the turrets off can you turn them back on and have them fight for you, or if you hack a computer and the turrets are already deactivated can you reactivate them and have them used to defend yourself?
The turrets are deadly to your companion and their power armor they tend to rush in and attack and it's quite annoying, Piper will always rush into the firing line of a turret and she is stubborn when you try and make her wait while you destroy the turret in a safe manner.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to target only enemies. At least not without reading a magazine for that.

Comment: as far as I know, if you hack a computer that control turrets, you can shut them on or off.

Comment: @Max - There are other options, but you have to find the corresponding hacking magazine to get these special behaviors.

Comment: Also related/possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246218/108003